# How can i group objects according to related objects attribute in django

Tags: django, group-by

I have these two models;

```
class Point(models.Model):
    point       = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField("Action", max_length=128)

class PointLog(models.Model):
    user   = models.ForeignKey('users.User', verbose_name ="Related User")
    point  = models.ForeignKey(Point)
    date   = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
```

The `Point` objects are static. I mean they don't change dynamically, it shows which action brings how many points. And PointLog objects show user's actions. A user can accomplish same action more than one.

I want to group `PointLog` objects according to user actions and sum each different action's point

Help :)

Sample Point Objects;

```
description      point
-----------------------
make comment     5
add photo        20
add video        50
```

Sample PointLog Objects;

```
User        point         date
------------------------------
user1    make comment     ....
user1    make comment     ....
user1    add photo        ....
user1    add photo        ....
user1    add photo        ....
user1    add photo        ....
user1    add video        ....
user1    add video        ....
user1    add video        ....
```

Sample result;

```
user1s action;
  make comment 10 points gained
  add photo    80 points gained
  add video    150 points gained
```

Comment: Please add some data for the Point class. Are you sure that you do not need a many-2-many relationship between Point and PointLog. Where is action defined?

Comment: (comment            2),
(add_new_photo      20),
(add_new_video      50)
first is description second is point

Comment: I am sorry, I do not get it, please provide in your post (not just in the comment) data for both, point, point log, and describe what the Grouping and Summing should return.

Comment: Sorry. there is one attribute (int field not foreign key) in PointLog class that show affected object's id. Can't i do this without changing the models?

Comment: Sorry for missing explanation.

Comment: User1's made 2 comments so gained 10 points (5+5), added 4 photo so gained 80 points (20+20+20+20), added 3 video so gained 150 points (50+50+50).

Comment: I was not sarcastic, it is really crystal clear now and obvious want you want to do, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointLog.objects.all().values('user','point__description').annotate(points_gained=Sum('point__point'))

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
result = PointLog.objects.all().values("user", 'point').annotate(num=Count("pk"))
```